# Access to this.$apollo from Vuex store with vue-apollo in NUXT?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I want to store the user that comes from the login on an action in the vuex store. But there is no access to `this.$apollo`.

```
export const actions = {
  UPSERT_USER({ commit }, { authUser, claims }) {
     this.$apollo
        .mutate({
          mutation: UPSERT_USER_MUTATION,
          variables: {
            id: user.uid,
            email: user.email,
            name: user.name,
            picture: user.picture,
          },
        })
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to access it like this:

```
export default {
  actions: {
    foo (store, payload) {
      let client = this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it works in this way. The problem is that when the mutation is called, onUserChange, `this.app.apolloProvider` is yet undefined. I fixed it with a sleep of 1 second... but I don't think that is a good idea. Do you know how to wait for apolloProvider to be ready on the store? then execute the mutate()?

Comment: Hmm yes sleeping for a second is not a good idea. Hard to say, but I am pretty sure you are not the first one dealing with apollo in store. Try to search for that a bit, probably your solution is somewhere out there waiting for you to find. I don't know honestly right now ;(

Comment: yes, thank you. I am using the Firebase Nuxt module, which calls an action when the user is logged in, but at the time the apollo provider is not yet ready in the store.

Answer (score 1):

Because I inject apolloProvider in my nuxt apollo plugin using,

```
inject("apollo", apolloProvider);
```

Then in my case I access it using,

```
export default {
  actions: {
    foo (store, payload) {
        let apolloClient = this.$apollo.defaultClient
    }
  }
}
```