# Apollo query inside nuxt.config.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

I'm trying to make a smart request in `nuxt` with `nuxt-apollo-module` in order to grab my routes for the `nuxt-sitemaps-module` (so I can create my sitemap with them).

I need to make this request from within `nuxt.config.js` file. I have tried this way with no luck (as `app` doesn't exist in this context). What would be the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

The relevant part of my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

module.exports = {

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/apollo',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap'
  ],

  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'https://example.com/graphql'
      }
    }
  },


  sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: 'https://example.com/',
    generate: true,
    cacheTime: 86400,
    trailingSlash: true,
    routes: async ({ app }) => {
      const myRoutes = ['/one-random-path/']
      let client = app.apolloProvider.defaultClient
      let myProductsQuery = gql`query {
          products {
              slug
          }
      }`
      let myBrandsQuery = gql`query {
          brands {
              slug
          }
      }`
      const myProducts = await client.query({ query: myProductsQuery })
      const myBrands = await client.query({ query: myBrandsQuery })

      return [myRoutes, ...myProducts, ...myBrands]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll digg into it, but is there a way you could use nuxtServerInit
Aswell, will it be a static site ? spa or ssr ?

Comment: SSR, but I will probably port it to netlify at some point. So far I have it working SSR with the sitemap generator, the only difference is that the requests were made with axios ( `import axios from 'axios'` and then used `axios.get`

Comment: Can't you moove to action other part than nuxt conifg?

Comment: Nope, that's the tricky part. I have to set the routes of the sitemap-module in the nuxt.config.js file

Comment: do you have a github repo i could take a look locally ?

Comment: yep, sure, send me your mail and I'll add you to my gitlab

Comment: I've just read this answer, maybe it could help
[Access to this.$apollo from Vuex store with vue-apollo in NUXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65630793)

Comment: Hi @CarlosFuentes, thanks for the message. The post you point helps you to have apollo in vuex store, but this is not the store, but the config file (nuxt.config.js)

Comment: Hi @joe82, i'm the nuxt sitemap module creator. You cannot use a Nuxt module directly from the `nuxt.config.js` script (see this Nuxt core member answer https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/242#issuecomment-544923463)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to generate it this way, but I'm sure there is a better way.

```sh
yarn add node-fetch apollo-boost
```

```js
sitemap: {
  routes: async () => {
    const routes = []
    const fetch = require("node-fetch")
    const { gql } = require("apollo-boost")
    const ApolloBoost = require("apollo-boost")
    const ApolloClient = ApolloBoost.default

    const client = new ApolloClient({
      fetch: fetch,
      uri: YOUR_API_ENDPOINT,
    })

    const fetchUsers = gql`
      query {
        users {
          id
        }
      }
    `

    const users = await client
      .query({
        query: fetchUsers,
      })
      .then((res) => res.data.users)

    users.forEach((user) => {
      routes.push({
        route: `/${user.id}`,
      })
    })

    return routes
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I gave up using Apollo. It was easier to use Axios. Moreover, no nneds to configure @nuxtjs/sitemap :

```
import axios from 'axios'

sitemap: {
    hostname: URL_SITE,
    gzip: true,
},
routes() {
    return axios({
        url: ENDPOINT,
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            query: `
                query GET_POSTS {
                    posts {
                        nodes {
                            slug
                        }
                    }
                }
            `,
        },
    }).then((result) => {
        return result.data.data.posts.nodes.map((post) => {
            return '/blog/' + post.slug
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was how I was able to do it with authentication. Got round to it by following the documentation here which had a Vue example: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/

Might be a cleaner way to do it with apollo-boost if you can also use auth?

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { ApolloLink, concat } from 'apollo-link'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

import globalQuery from './apollo/queries/global.js'

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: process.env.SCHEMA_URL, fetch })

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  const token = process.env.STRAPI_API_TOKEN
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : 'Bearer',
    },
  })
  return forward(operation)
})

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})

export default async () => {
  let global = null
  const globalResponse = await apolloClient.query({ query: globalQuery })
  if (globalResponse?.data?.global?.data) {
    global = globalResponse.data.global.data.attributes
  }

  console.log('globals:::', global)
}
```